# How to create image zoom effect (Not on hover)

Tags: css, image

If you visit https://menupages.com/ you will see the background image automatically zooms in upon page load. How is this effect achieved?

Comment: Did you try $(document).ready(function) ? It looks like the background image is set to translate as soon as the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive that effect by playing with Keyframe, transform:scale & opacity of the image.

Something like this.

```
    keyframe zoomIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.25);
    }
}
```

And append it to an img element or class.

```
img {
...
animation-name: zoomIn;

}
```

To be eye pleased, the image should be 2X in their aspect ratio.